# FileNotFoundError on Heroku after creating that file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, heroku, logging

My app has some additional logging, it works fine on a local machine and even on Heroku local. When I push it to Heroku, it raises a `FileNotFoundError`. Here is my code:

```py
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, name, file_handler, formatter, stream_handler):
        if not os.path.exists('Logs'):
            os.makedirs('Logs')

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        if stream_handler:
            stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)


logger_dev = Logger('dev',
                    handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(f'Logs/dev.log', when='midnight', backupCount=2),
                    logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(filename)s : %(funcName)s : %(message)s'),
                    True)

logger_usr = Logger('usr',
                    handlers.RotatingFileHandler(f'Logs/usr.log', maxBytes=7 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=2),
                    logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(message)s'),
                    False)
```

I've also tried explicitly creating `.log` files by adding this to the Logger class:

```py
if not os.path.exists(f'Logs/{name}.log'):
    open(f'Logs/{name}.log', 'w+').close()
```

Here are Heroku logs:

```
2020-06-15T20:59:43.441969+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-15T20:59:43.441997+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 8, in <module>
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442110+00:00 app[worker.1]: import settings as s
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442114+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/settings.py", line 60, in <module>
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442251+00:00 app[worker.1]: handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(f'Logs/dev.log', when='midnight', backupCount=2),
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442254+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/logging/handlers.py", line 200, in __init__
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442437+00:00 app[worker.1]: BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding, delay)
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442439+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/logging/handlers.py", line 55, in __init__
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442606+00:00 app[worker.1]: logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
2020-06-15T20:59:43.442622+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1143, in __init__
2020-06-15T20:59:43.443050+00:00 app[worker.1]: StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
2020-06-15T20:59:43.443054+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1172, in _open
2020-06-15T20:59:43.443475+00:00 app[worker.1]: return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
2020-06-15T20:59:43.443501+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/Logs/dev.log'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't log to files on Heroku. Its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) means that anything you write could be lost at any time, and *will* be lost at least daily.

Instead, log to `stderr` or `stdout`. Then Heroku can [incorporate your logs into its log stream](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log):

> A Heroku app’s logs are aggregated from the output streams of all of its running processes, system components, and backing services

Logs are mostly transient on Heroku, so you might want to set up a [logging addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#logging) or [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains):

> The `logs` command retrieves 100 log lines by default. You can specify the number of log lines to retrieve (up to a maximum of 1,500 lines) by using the `--num` (or `-n`) option.

Comment: The idea here is to be able to download these log files. This is a bot, and there is a function to download user activity history, that's why I've set it up like that in the first place.

Comment: That's irrelevant. You can literally lose them _at any moment_. Log to the output streams. This is [part of Heroku's fundamental design](https://12factor.net/logs).

Comment: I get that, but how do I produce logs that can be stored and retrieved then?

Comment: Don't think of logs as files. As described in the link I provided in my previous comment, think of them as streams. If you want to do something with them, set up a logging addon or log drain as I suggested and get them from there.