# FileNotFoundError: A json file not found after pushing it to heroku

Tags: python, json, django, heroku, file-not-found

I am working on a website. For this website I have to create a table which shows the time of the meeting and the participants of it. I am writing the code of site using Django. For the table I have a data on a `.json` file. When I run the server locally it works fine and when I push it to heroku it raises `FileNotFoundError`. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397348/filenotfounderror-on-heroku-after-creating-that-file) which faces with the similar problem but the answer shows how to log something, but I need  `.json` file for data. My django app directory:

```
            66 admin.py
           100 apps.py
<DIR>          migrations
            60 models.py
         3,332 schedule_of_teams.json
<DIR>          static
<DIR>          templates
            63 tests.py
           333 urls.py
           807 views.py
```

So I have a view function in `views.py` file:

```py
def schedule_of_teams(request):
    with open('./schedule_of_teams.json',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        context = json.load(f)
    context['title'] = 'Yarış cədvəli'
    
    return render(request,'schedule_of_teams.html',context)
```

And open context manager raises the error:

```py
FileNotFoundError at /schedule_of_teams/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory './schedule_of_teams.json/'
```

So why is this happening? Why it works fine when I run `python manage.py runserver` with localhost but when I push to heroku  it raises this exception? Is heroku ignores `.json` files? By the way, I do not have `*.json` on my `.gitignore` file it commits the file.

**What I have tried:**

I tried to change the directory of the file like moving it to a folder `data/` or firstly instead of `open('./schedule_of_teams.json)` I wrote `open('schedule_of_teams.json')` but that didn't work either.

I am literally so confused I asked this question in Python Discord Server but got no respond. One of the solutions is creating a database but I do not want to do it, since this data is just a list which has 16 dictionaries and each has 4 keys.

Comment: you added the file in git right? like `git add schedule_of_teams.json`? and commited the changes. did you check the filesystem on your running app? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924458/how-to-see-files-and-file-structure-on-a-deployed-heroku-app. maybe its a problem with the dots and slashes, did you try to remove them?

Comment: @hansTheFranz yeah like I said first I tried only the file name which gave the error. And yes I have added that file and committed the changes.